# How to build SVMstruct Python module on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, glibc, eglibc

I downloaded the source code from [here](http://svmlight.joachims.org/svm_struct.html).  When I run make, I get the following error message:

```
make: Entering directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204'
cd svm_light; make svm_learn_hideo_noexe
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204/svm_light'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `svm_learn_hideo_noexe'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204/svm_light'
cd svm_struct; make svm_struct_noexe
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204/svm_struct'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `svm_struct_noexe'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204/svm_struct'
gcc -g -lm svm_struct/svm_struct_learn.o svm_struct_api.o svm_light/svm_hideo.o svm_light/svm_learn.o svm_light/svm_common.o svm_struct/svm_struct_common.o svm_struct/svm_struct_main.o pyobjs/array.o pyobjs/constraints.o pyobjs/default.o pyobjs/document.o pyobjs/kernelparm.o pyobjs/model.o pyobjs/sample.o pyobjs/sparm.o pyobjs/sparse.o pyobjs/structmodel.o pyobjs/svmapi.o -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil  -o svm_python_learn
/usr/bin/ld: svm_light/svm_common.o: undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [svm_python_learn_hideo] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204'
christopher@christopher-laptop:~/SourceCode/svm-python-v204-build$ make -C ./../svm-python-v204
make: Entering directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204'
cd svm_light; make svm_learn_hideo_noexe
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204/svm_light'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `svm_learn_hideo_noexe'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204/svm_light'
cd svm_struct; make svm_struct_noexe
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204/svm_struct'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `svm_struct_noexe'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204/svm_struct'
gcc -g -lm svm_struct/svm_struct_learn.o svm_struct_api.o svm_light/svm_hideo.o svm_light/svm_learn.o svm_light/svm_common.o svm_struct/svm_struct_common.o svm_struct/svm_struct_main.o pyobjs/array.o pyobjs/constraints.o pyobjs/default.o pyobjs/document.o pyobjs/kernelparm.o pyobjs/model.o pyobjs/sample.o pyobjs/sparm.o pyobjs/sparse.o pyobjs/structmodel.o pyobjs/svmapi.o -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil  -o svm_python_learn
/usr/bin/ld: svm_light/svm_common.o: undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [svm_python_learn_hideo] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/christopher/SourceCode/svm-python-v204'
```

Everything is fairly 'out of the box' so I suspect this is a Ubuntu problem.  In particular, I suspect glibc is out of date from

```
undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

When I try `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, I get

```
GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) stable release version 2.19
```

The latest version is 2.2.5, but eglibc, which seems to be how Ubuntu users get glibc, doesn't have a [2.2 branch](http://www.eglibc.org/repository).  I have already tried `apt-get upgrade` but I am still at version 2.19.  What do I do to solve this?

---

As of 2014, Debian seems to have moved back to glibc.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `LIBS=-lm` near the top of the MakeFile to link against the math library solved the problem for me.